# The right way to detect tcp broken connection ? Manual keepalive idle , and don't worked SetWriteDeadLine

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, go

I have some problem with a TCP connection.

I have a server written in go which listen tcp connection on some port.
And I have client written in Java for Android.
Client establish connection with server, and then exchange some data both without any laws.

When Android changes the network type, for example from mobile network to wifi. Connection is broken, but server don't know about this problem, and think that client all ready to take a some data.

I need to detect this problem on my server so quick as possible. Ideally immediately

First I used in go `SetKeepAlive(true)` and `SetKeepAlivePeriod(10 * time.Second)`. It's worked, but not quickly as I need. Because go SetKeepAlivePeriod, set **tcp keepalive time(idle)** and **tcp keepalive interval** to same. For example in linux **tcp keepalive retry=8**, then problem with connection detected after (10 + 8*10) = 90sec = 1 min 30sec. It is very very slow :(. How to set idle and interval manual ? I watching this lib https://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive, but I don't trust this lib, because, in this lib socket fd copying without clear.

I can set `SetKeepAlivePeriod(1 * time.Second)`, but whats about performance ? In my case, connection may be a heavily loaded or idle.

Then, i think about SetWriteDeadline. It's very useful for me, because i don't know when i receive message from client, but i know when i send message to client. But when i used SetWriteDeadline, is not working.
For example

```go
var request *http.Request

conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second))
err := request.Write(conn)
if err != nil {
    if neterr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && neterr.Timeout() {
        log.Println("Connection WriteDeadline timeout")
    }
    conn.Close();
} else {
    conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Time{})
}
```

When after connection broken on client, I Write some data into connection, method Write return nil without error. As though data already send and server success accepted ACK from client, but how ?

**Update 28.10.2015 22:35**

I decided to try this https://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive library. And yet it works perfectly for my problem :).

```go
ka, _ := tcpkeepalive.EnableKeepAlive(conn)
ka.SetKeepAliveCount(2)
ka.SetKeepAliveInterval(3 * time.Second)
ka.SetKeepAliveIdle(10 * time.Second)
```

Comment: Set a socket read timeout.

Comment: @EJP How to do this in golang ?

Comment: @sintanial: [`conn.SetReadDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetReadDeadline)

Answer (score 1):

to make thing simple, please do not use TCP level things to make sure your business session things. what you need in real is detecting broken session, so keep sending ping-pong in business level. you can calculate the load simply, like a "ping" string with tcp header, should be in 30bytes.

Comment: "ping" is four bytes; a TCP header is at least 20 bytes; and the IP header is another 20. Total 44.

Comment: well my mistake, it should be less than 30 bytes, not 20, as ip should not included. because almost everything has ip layer, we can not avoid it.

Comment: So it's free? Come off it. 44 bytes.

Comment: @EJP 1st, tcp keep live and other ways also need IP overload. 2nd, if you want to count the bytes in whole stack, we need 802.3/802.11/3G-mobile/4G-mobile/EDGE/GPRS ... all level. final, that not make scene.

Comment: @JiangYD why is business session things ? I need to detect broken connection, for this problem invented heartbeat like keepalive. Why I must use my implementation over tcp ?

And somebody explain to me why does not work SetWriteDeadline ?

Comment: because it is easy and more clear doing heatbeat in application level. SetWriteDeadline just check socket write, and socket write just move data from application to kernel tcp buffer, it always no error if the buffer not full.

Comment: @JiangYD thx for answer. Why SetWriteDeadline created, if we have Write method which return error immediately, if failed write to socket ?
And why need ACK in TCP proto if i can't detected, when data is transferred to client successfully

Comment: it's for blocking i think, you can use this to avoid the write operation blocked forever; you need a ACK and a timeout to check whether you lost the client, because a `TCPConn` can not tell you the data is transferred to client successfully.

Comment: I haven't said anything about keepalive, and not all 'other ways need IP overhead'. I suggested a read timeout. Space cost: zero.