# GO: Exceeds 10000-thread on simple tcp server?

Tags: multithreading, tcp, go

I need to write a tcp server which can handle more than 500k connections.

I wrote a simple server on golang, but when connections more than 10k, the server crashed with the error message "runtime: program exceeds 10000-thread limit fatal error: thread exhaustion".

Server runs in last linux build. That go can use epoll for tcp connection, to make it async and use few fd. So why does the server exceed the thread limit?!

My simple server:

```
package main
import (
    "strconv"
    "net"
    "log"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "io"
)

type Handler struct {
    conn   net.Conn
    closed chan bool
}

func (h *Handler) Listen() { // listen connection for incomming data
    defer h.conn.Close()
    bf := bufio.NewReader(h.conn)
    for {
        line, _, err := bf.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                log.Println("End connection")
            }
            h.closed <- true // send to dispatcher, that connection is closed
            return
        }

        // ... some business logic with data
    }
}

type Dispatcher struct {
    handlers map[string]*Handler `map[ip]*Handler`
}

func (d *Dispatcher) AddHandler(conn net.Conn) {
    addr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
    handler := &Handler{conn, make(chan bool, 1)}
    d.handlers[addr] = handler

    go handler.Listen()

    <-handler.closed // when connection closed, remove handler from handlers
    delete(d.handlers, addr)
}

func (d *Dispatcher) ListenHandlers(port int) {
    sport := strconv.Itoa(port)

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":" + sport)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept() // accept connection
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        tcpconn := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
        tcpconn.SetKeepAlive(true)
        tcpconn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(10 * time.Second)

        go d.AddHandler(conn)
    }
}

func main() {
    dispatcher := &Dispatcher{make(map[string]*Handler)}
    dispatcher.ListenHandlers(3000)
}
```

**Update 11.10.2015**
The problem was that https://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive library. Please do not use it :)

Comment: I don't think routers can handle 500k connections.

Comment: Whenever a goroutine makes a blocking syscall or goes to call C code in a library, go uses a new thread for other goroutines. I suspect that the part commented as `// ... some business logic with data` has something blocking that causes go to spin extra goroutines.  Are you per chance calling some C code in that part?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer No, I'm not calling some C code. Furthermore data from the clients come very rarely... so business logic calling very rarely too.

Comment: @YOU why you so think ? Golang designed for net communications, and IMHO 500K in our time it's not so much :) ?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Also, why go create new thread for every blocking syscall, in net/tcp golang by default using epoll which can handle many fd in small numbers of threads ?!

Comment: one big project I knew of have 20 million user login targeted for 20k at maximum peak usage with 10+ servers load-balanced. your 500k is obviously unrealistic.

Comment: @YOU you talkink about 20k http requests at the same time, which connected, executed, and died. And I talking about long time tcp keep alive connections. In internet has many examples about 1 million keep alive connections on node.js( which working in one threads :) ), and other language like erlang, java and of course  c/c++

Comment: @sintanial: Go's `net` package will multiplex reads and writes to multiple sockets using epoll/select.  Have you tried inspecting the app with gdb to see what al the threads are doing when you see this error?

Comment: @James Henstridge Thx for answer, I'll try it now :)

Comment: TCP connections use up one port on each peer. The ports are represented by 16 bit numbers, so there you have a technological limit on the number of TCP connections that you can have on a single IP address which is far from your goal of 0.5M connections. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt AFAIK from multiple source addresses and ports, you can have more than 65k connections, as each connection has two addresses it is identified by.

Comment: By the way, your `Dispatcher.AddHandler` is a [giant data race](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) making the entire behaviour of your program undefined. You cannot add or delete elements from a map concurrently.

Comment: @DaveC your are right, it's example, in real app i use mutex to work in concurrent.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer you were right. I remove my business logic, and run server, and it's works fine. Running in 34 threads and thats all, threads not increasing :). Thx for your, I thought that in the golang problem :)

Comment: @sintanial so what in your business logic blocked the execution and made go's scheduler spawn more threads? You should read about go's scheduler BTW, it will make all this less mysterious :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer a few weeks ago, i published this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238082/the-right-way-to-detect-tcp-broken-connection-manual-keepalive-idle-and-don/32239407, where i used this library https://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive. The problem was just out of this library

Comment: @sintanial Nice digging! Could you please answer your own question and accept the answer :)

Comment: Could you describe the exact problem the library caused? Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg problem already reported, but unfortunately author not have amount of time, to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that https://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive library. 
This library get socket file descriptor (fd), copy then and worked with new fd, which running in blocked mode. Therefore, go created new thread on every connect. Go don't kill created thread (because this is native golang behavior), and after some times go failed with "Exceeds 10000-thread". That's it !
Please do not use it :)